# how can i start update only after I click a button (Newbie on Unity & in coding)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a countdown timer with the use of the Update() however when I run unity the countdown starts automatically, I want it to start only after I clicked a button. When I take away the button function it seems to work, but then again I need the button so the timer won't start automatically...any help is appreciated!

(Full code...if it helps)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Text countdownText;
    public AudioSource audioData;
    public Button m_timer1;

    private bool timerOn;
    
    float minutes = 0;
    float seconds = 3;
    float miliseconds = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        audioData = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

        timerOn = false;

        Button btn = m_timer1.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(ClickBtn);

    }

    public void ClickBtn()
    {
        //Debug.Log("doesthiswork???!!");
        timerOn = true;
        Invoke(Update);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (timerOn == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Yo");
            if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0 && miliseconds <= 0)// timerOn = false
            {
                timerOn = false;
                //Debug.Log("CurrentTime = 0");
                Music_Play();

            }

            else if (miliseconds <= 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("ithasreachedthisstage");
                if (seconds <= 0)
                {
                    minutes--;
                    seconds = 59;
                }

                else if (seconds >= 0)
                {
                    seconds--;
                }

                miliseconds = 100;
            }

            miliseconds -= Time.deltaTime * 100;

            countdownText.text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", minutes, seconds); //countdown
        }
      
    }

    void Music_Play() //this works, now make the button work!!!
    {
        audioData.Play();
        //Debug.Log("musicon");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to make a coroutine to handles the timer, or even add a bool to your class that when it becomes true(setting to true in your clickbtn) then it decrements in update.

Comment: Just disable/enable the component(s). Update ist only executed on enabled components while a direct method call via the button still is executed -> disable the component in Awake and use the button to enable the component

Comment: In the declaration `private bool timerOn = false;` you shouldn't `Invoke(Update);` as it's always invoked because it's a monobehaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update only runs when component.enabled==true;
If you untick the checkbox next to component name, it will not start its update until its enabled. You can easily attach this to an UI[image] button